# Which sudoku logic should I apply here?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image: sudoku]

I was able to eliminate 1 in r8c1(in short selected cell) using Finn X wing using 1's on r17c15 and Finn is on r7c3. But it seems like that logic is not enough to make it to half way of this sudoku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your pencilmarks there is only one place to put

> a 6 in column 5.

You also have

> a naked pair 47 in row 4 so R4C4 cannot be a 7 and must be a 6.

After that it can be solved using only singles.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add pencilmarks 6 on column 5 and r46. Naked pair was brilliant !!

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Yes, I thought that might be a mistake, so I added the pair just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much naked pair was the missing logic here

Answer (score 1):

More ways to make progress using:

> Locked candidates

For example:

> All of the 8's in box 4 are in the same column so you can eliminate the rest of the 8's in that column (r7c3).

> All of the 5's in box 1 are in the same row so you can eliminate the rest of the 5's in that row (r3c9).

Further:

> Uniqueness pattern: r5c8 cannot contain a 4 or a 7 since it would create a deadly rectangle with r4c1, r5c1, r4c8 where a unique solution would not exist because you could never disambiguate the placement of the 4's and 7's in those cells.